# How to remove the last element of a jQuery selection?

Tags: jquery, iterator, css-selectors

I use a jquery selector :

```
$('#menus>ul>li>a')
```

I'd like to to iterate the selector result without the last one:

```
$('#menus>ul>li>a').removeLast().each(fct());
```

Ofcourse the function "removeLast()" doesn't exist, is there an equivalent ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `:not` selector or the `.not()` method:

```
$('#menus>ul>li>a:not(:last)')
```

or

```
$('#menus>ul>li>a').not(":last")
```

Comment: The parameter to `not` in your second example should use a `:` instead of a `.`.

Answer (score 9):

Use a combination of the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selectors:

```
$('#menus > ul > li > a:not(:last)')
```